# PGA2311 Digital Power Supply (+5V) shared with other ICs or not

Tags: power-supply, audio

I am working on Audio Volume Controller, based on [Texas Instruments PGA2311 Stereo Audio Volume Controller](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pga2311.pdf). Among other pins, this IC has also `Digital Power Supply (+5V) Pin`. Can I use these `+5V` from power supply also for other integrated ciruits on `PCB` (beside powering `PGA2311`) or should I consecrate one power line for `PGA2311` and one power line for other ICs? I am aware of current capabilities of regulator, I am asking if quality of audio signal reproduction would have suffered if I shared power line among all ICs (digital) on PCB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the datasheet recommendations and all should be well.

[image]

*Figure 1. Don't skip any of the recommended capacitors. Keep the digital and analogue grounds separate except for the one connection point between the two.*

The correct grounding is emphasised on the PCB floor plan.

[image]

*Figure 2. The floor plan emphasises the one connection between digital and audio grounds.*

Comment: A ferrite bead between the analog and digital grounds might be a good idea too, as well as one in each of the analog supply lines maybe.